# send json from servlet when hit URL

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I have a servlet page and I want to send data from servlet to jsp when user hit respective url. I mean that is mapped to that servlet page.

Comment: A more elaborate explanation and some code will help ppl understand exactly what you're trying to do..

Comment: I want to send json to jsp page when I enter url which is mentioned below in url-pattern.                                                                                      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javaAngularJS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.AngularJsServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javaAngularJS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/javaAngularJS</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Please give us detailed information and some piece of code from your code